# Perf tool and dlopen

Tags: c++, dlopen, perf

Is it possible to profile a library that is loaded via dlopen with the perf tool?

So far, I was not able to get readable results. Somehow, the profiler seems to have problems with resolving the addresses in the library. Furthermore, I have the problem that perf complains about the following command:

```
perf record -e cycles:p -p
```

Error: 'precise' request may not be supported. Try removing 'p' modifier.

Any idea?

Comment: For your last error, I suggest you remove ":p".
About the initial problem, could you explicit "not able to get readable results"?
I don't know about dlopen behaviour with perf. Have you tried with the option "-a"?

Comment: Please provide kernel version `uname -a`, perf version `perf --version` and CPU info `less /proc/cpuinfo`